# Configuring JPA(Hibernate) with Tomcat 8.0

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jpa, provider

I have problem with configuring Tomcat 8.0 with JPA using Hibernate as a provider in Eclipse. 
When i tried to use DataSource Annotation and standard JDBC way to connect to DB, the connection is ok but when i try to use Hibernate and i get an exception about there is no provider for my PU. I tried to move hibernate libs to many directories (web-inf/lib, apache TC library) but i still get the same exception. I think the data source is configured properly.
Below i add my configured files.

web.xml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>HibernateTest</display-name>
    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/HibernateTest</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>`

persistence.xml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="HibernateTest" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/HibernateTest</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>`

context.xml in tomcat(only fragment)

`<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <Resource name="jdbc/HibernateTest" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="admin" password="admin" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
               url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Hibernate"/>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>`

```
public TestServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HibernateTest");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    em.close();
    emf.close();

}
```

}
`

Comment: See if prefixing `jta-data-source` name in `context.xml` with `java:comp/env/` helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since Tomcat is a servlet container (as opposed to a full blown J2EE application server), JTA doesn't come with it. If you want to use JTA in Tomcat, you have to drop in an implementation of your choice.